# How do I increase the reader quota on WCF service?

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, readerquotas

I don't expect anyone to be able to help out with this but let's give it a go.

I have a WinForms app that uses a WCF service to pull down a rather large JSON document serialised into a string. I have changed the client's Reader Quota on strings to 8192000 (arbitrary but suitable for most cases) and put the service onto a custom binding with an explicit readerquota of 8192000

checking the service reference in Notepad by eye the quota in the .svcinfo files is set to 8192 although this could be a red herring.

I'm at the end of my tether, I've followed every piece of advice I can find on Google:

- http://www.haveyougotwoods.com/archive/2008/03/29/wcf-and-large-messages.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163394.aspx

to name but two and all the suggested answers I could find on here i.e.

- [WCF service The maximum array length quota (16384) has been exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068076/wcf-service-the-maximum-array-length-quota-16384-has-been-exceeded)
- [WCF Maximum Message Size Quota](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708804/wcf-maximum-message-size-quota)
- [Maximum array length quota](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464707/wcf-maximum-array-length-quota)

and I looked at this:

http://wildermuth.com/2009/09/10/Using_Large_Message_Requests_in_Silverlight_with_WCF

which was a response to one of the above or one of the many other things I have looked at that I have not retrieved from my "Recently Closed Tabs" list.

Basically I can't think of anything else to do to increase this limit and yet it still insists upon first encountering a string longer than 64k in length that the limits have not been altered at all.

So could anyone just give me a really basic step-by-step to altering this one setting for a WinForms app serialising and then deserialising JSON data as a string on either end of the transaction? A lot of the other advice has been about silverlight or some other scenario and for whatever reason it just fails to affect this case.

Comment: What error exactly are you getting? Remember there are several different quotas, and you might be running into a different one.

Comment: Nope the exact error relates to the MaxStringContentLength quota (or whatever) the number 8192, referenced exactly in the error message, is now burned into my mind.

Comment: What about showing some client code and configuration?

Comment: Okay this tells me everything I need to know. Unless someone went "Ah yes, this is that annoying problem where..." I really am on my own here. So, I guess I am. This really needs to work so I am hoping that completely rebuilding the target app from scratch works out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the solution as shown in the last article I linked to again, just to go over my previous work. This time instead of preventing the WCF services from working at all (which is what had happened previously) it instead started to work and upped the limits.

I don't know what I was doing wrong the first time or what I did right this time... one of those things I guess.